# Calculate frequency of a list of values in descending order and its associated percentage of values higher

Tags: python, frequency, percentage

I am trying to write a Python code that calculates for a given list of values (y) in descending order the frequency for each y value and the associated percentage of samples(yi) with larger y value taking into account the frequency.

Thanks very much!
This is the Python code I'v written using NumPy but I get some errors while calculating the percentages and when calculating the frequency I want it to be in order in consistency with the new array of y values without repetitions (arr)

```
# Permeability values (mD)
y = [27.10, 23.02, 18.26, 17.46, 16.88, 15.75, 15.21, 12.65, 12.65, 12.65, 12.65,  14.93, 13.88, 13.53, 13.31, 13.27, 12.65, 12.41, 11.97, 11.93, 11.84, 11.82, 27.10, 27.10, 27.10, 11.12, 11.10, 10.65, 10.54, 10.29, 9.98, 9.19, 9.03, 8.56, 8.28, 8.21, 9.98, 9.98, 11.97, 11.97, 11.97, 4.68, 4.37, 3.82, 3.44, 3.38, 3.33, 3.27, 3.22, 2.52, 2.38, 1.91, 1.89, 1.87, 1.81, 1.00, 13.27, 13.27, 9.98, 13.27, 9.98, 13.27, 9.98, 13.27]

# Permeability values in descending order (y, mD)
y_sorted = sorted(y, reverse=True)

# Calculate frequency for the permeability values in descending order
y_new_sorted = np.array(y_sorted)
arr,count = np.unique(y_new_sorted,return_counts=True)
arr_sorted = sorted(arr, reverse=True)
print('Frequency= ', count)
print('Permeability values in descending order without repititions= ', arr_sorted)

# Percentage of samples with larger permeability (x, %)
vec_percent = np.vectorize(percent)
np.unique(vec_percent(y_new_sorted))
print('Percentage of samples with larger permeability= ', vec_percent)
     
**OUTPUTS**

Frequency=  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 6 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 1 5 6 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 4]

Permeability values in descending order without repititions=  [27.1, 23.02, 18.26, 17.46, 16.88, 15.75, 15.21, 14.93, 13.88, 13.53, 13.31, 13.27, 12.65, 12.41, 11.97, 11.93, 11.84, 11.82, 11.12, 11.1, 10.65, 10.54, 10.29, 9.98, 9.19, 9.03, 8.56, 8.28, 8.21, 4.68, 4.37, 3.82, 3.44, 3.38, 3.33, 3.27, 3.22, 2.52, 2.38, 1.91, 1.89, 1.87, 1.81, 1.0]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File line 22, in <module>
    vec_percent = np.vectorize(percent)
NameError: name 'percent' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways, using traditional `list` or using efficient `numpy`:

**Using Lists**

```py
>>> y = [390, 390, 390, 390, 390, 370, 370, 350, 330, 330, 330, 330, 330, 330, 310, 310, 310, 310, 290]
#declare a lambda function to calculate percentage and frequency
>>> freq = lambda x: y.count(x)
>>> percent = lambda z: y.index(z)/len(y)
#after this using map() and mapping over only unique values rather than all
>>> print(list(map(freq,set(y))))
[1, 5, 6, 2, 4, 1]
>>> print(list(map(percent,set(y))))
[0.9473684210526315, 0.0, 0.42105263157894735, 0.2631578947368421, 0.7368421052631579, 0.3684210526315789]
>>> set(y)
{290, 390, 330, 370, 310, 350}
#frequency and percent corresponds here to respective values
```

**Using Numpy**

*I would recommend using this cause its fast and efficient but you will see better results only if you have a relatively larger dataset to work on.*

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> y_new = np.array(y)
>>> arr,count = np.unique(y_new,return_counts=True) #very simple approach to get output
>>> count
array([1, 4, 6, 1, 2, 5])
>>> arr
array([290, 310, 330, 350, 370, 390])
#defining vectorized percentage function refering to what defined previously
>>> vec_percent = np.vectorize(percent)
>>> np.unique(vec_percent(y_new))
array([0.        , 0.26315789, 0.36842105, 0.42105263, 0.73684211,
       0.94736842])
#you get your percentages
```

Now its upon you what to use.

Comment: Thank you very much @JenilDave for your brilliant answer. I am more keen to use NumPy but I would like if you could do the same as you did for the NumPy method but in a descending order for the new list of y values without repetitions i.e. (390, 370, 350, 330, 310, 290) and also for the frequencies list i.e. (5, 2, 1, 6, 4, 1). Appreciated!

Comment: @5544 For the same `arr` can be processed as `np.sort(arr)[::-1]` to get in descending also the values of the retrieved arrays of percent and count stored as `p` for percent and `c` for count, `p[::-1]` and `c[::-1]` will do for you. (Note we will not sort `p` and `c` !)

Comment: yes I'v sorted in descending order the arr, but I want to order also the count (frequeny) in consistency with the order of arr. Hopefully you understand what I mean. Thanks!

Comment: Just do as I said in the above comment, you will get that.

Comment: yes I did that but when calculating the percentage is giving me errors 'name 'percent' is not defined'.

Comment: You might not have defined that check using lists code, line 3 I have declared percent.  Use this `percent = lambda z: y_new.index(z)/len(y_new)`

Answer (score 2):

### Basic

`list.count(item)` function returns the number of times that `item` can be found inside `list`.
`list.index(item)` function returns the position of the first `item` inside the list, which happens to be the number of elements that are before it (as python starts indexing lists by 0) and as it is ordered in a decreshing fashion, this happens to be the number of higher values.

```py
y = [390, 390, 390, 390, 390, 370, 370, 350, 330, 330, 330, 330, 330, 330, 310, 310, 310, 310, 290]

def freq(item, lst):
    return lst.count(item)

def higher_perc(item, lst):
    return lst.index(item) / len(lst)

print(freq(370, y))  # 2
print(higher_perc(370, y))  # 0.2631578947368421
```

If we want to apply it to multiple values we can make a function that returns a function that applies the operation and then use `map`:

```py
y = [390, 390, 390, 390, 390, 370, 370, 350, 330, 330, 330, 330, 330, 330, 310, 310, 310, 310, 290]
items = sorted(set(y), reverse=True)

def create_freq_function(lst):
    def freq(item):
        return lst.count(item)
    return freq

def create_higher_perc_function(lst):
    def higher_perc(item):
        return lst.index(item) / len(lst)
    return higher_perc

print(items)
# [390, 370, 350, 330, 310, 290]
print(list(map(create_freq_function(y), items))
# [5, 2, 1, 6, 4, 1]
print(list(map(create_higher_perc_function(y), items))
# [0.0, 0.2631578947368421, 0.3684210526315789, 0.42105263157894735, 0.7368421052631579, 0.9473684210526315]
```

### Numpy

If the dataset is to big, `numpy` package will help. `numpy.unique` works both to get the list of unique items as well as the number of times they appear, while `numpy.cumsum` allows to accumulate the percentage of individual elements.

```py
import numpy as np

y = np.array([390, 390, 390, 390, 390, 370, 370, 350, 330, 330, 330, 330, 330, 330, 310, 310, 310, 310, 290])

items, freqs = np.unique(y, return_counts=True)
items, freqs = items[::-1], freqs[::-1]
perc_freqs = freqs/len(y)
higher_percs = np.cumsum(perc_freqs) - perc_freqs

print(items)
# [390 370 350 330 310 290]
print(freqs)
# [5 2 1 6 4 1]
print(higher_percs)
# [0.         0.26315789 0.36842105 0.42105263 0.73684211 0.94736842]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Adirio, I would like to do it also for the whole n values of the list so I can later on apply it for larger data sets!

Comment: @5544 Done! The numpy solution focuses on performance while the basic solution is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function for the frequencies calculation :

```
def frequencies(values, display_flag=True):
  freq = {}
  for val in values:
    if str(val) in freq:
      freq[str(val)] += 1
    else:
      freq[str(val)] = 1
  
  # Displaying frequencies
  if display_flag:
    for i in (sorted (freq.keys())) : 
      print("Frequency of " + i + " is : " + str(freq[i]))

  return freq
```

And you can use this function for the percentages calculation:

```
def percentages(values):
  freq = frequencies(values, False)
  total = len(values)
  current = 0

  for i in (sorted (freq.keys())) :
    temp = freq[i]/total
    print("Percentage of " + i + " is : " + str(current + temp))
    current += temp
```

Notice that the `percentages` function works with the `frequencies` function

Comment: Thank you @Xeyes. How can I apply this for the whole n values in the y list so I can apply it later on for larger data sets. Thanks!

Comment: My function assumes that "values" parameter already is list of values, you can thus give your "y" variable as parameter of this function

Comment: I edited my answer to add the percentages function allowing you to do the second thing you asked

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer @Xeyes. Could you please apply it to my case using y as the parameter and my values so I can follow it and understand it properly. Thanks!

Comment: You just have to call my functions doing this : frequencies(y)       and : percentages(y)